# CodeIgniter parser addon

Tags: codeigniter, parsing, if-statement

Can't load my_parser class.
Added this http://codepad.org/QtHsyRN3 to application/libraries
than in controller i wrote

```
$this->load->library('my_parser');
```

but i am getting

```
Unable to load the requested class: my_parser
```

What can be? I need something like this

```
{if 10 > 8}10 is greater then 8<br />{/if}
```

But without smarty and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user guide states you shouldn't include the 'MY_' when calling the library, so:

```
$this->load->library('parser');
```

should work - see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: It's **<?php
$this->load->library('parser');
$this->load->library('my_parser'); ...** my_parser is not default CodeIgniter parser but added library.

Comment: Yes, but its already works fine, my .php file was not "my_parser.php", changed it and now everything is ok! So solutions is "class name = .php file name"

Answer (score 0):

.php file was wrong name. Solutions is **"class name = .php file name"**